# Averaging multi-dimensional arrays across several dimensions at once

Tags: arrays, matlab

Assume I have a 5-dimensional array X, and I want to compute the mean value (a scalar) of its elements across several dimensions at once, e.g. the last three dimensions given specified values for the first two.

I tried `mean(X(1, 1, :, :, :))`, but that does not give me the desired result, i.e. it produces an array output rather than a scalar output.

My workaround has been to do for loops to compute the mean across each dimension, and then manually compute the mean of all these partial (marginal) means. But this is cumbersome, as it involves writing more code, which often ends up confusing me.

Is there a simple trick to make this aim achievable using a call to the `mean` function similar to the one above?

Comment: You want the mean of ALL values vertical and horzontal for each unique value of the first two columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to first `reshape` your data so that you flatten the last three dimensions and then take the mean of that along that third dimension.

```
M = mean(reshape(X, size(X, 1), size(X, 2), []), 3);
```

The nice thing here is that this does not create a copy of `X` in memory since `reshape` simply changes the way that the *same* data is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to perform average/mean calculations for specific elements along the first two dimensions -

```
% Random input array and specific indices for dimension-1,2
X = randi(9,3,5,4,2,4);
dim12_idx = [1,1; 2,4; 3,1; 3,3]

% Store size parameters
[d1,d2,~] = size(X);

% Reshape input array to 2D merging first two dims as one, merging rest as other 
Xr = reshape(X,d1*d2,[]);

% Calculate the linear index equivalent of the specific indices
lidx = sub2ind([d1,d2],dim12_idx(:,1),dim12_idx(:,2));

% Index into the rows of reshaped array with those and perform mean along
% columns for the final output
out = mean(Xr(lidx,:),2)
```

**Issue with the original approach**

Now, your approach of `mean(X(1, 1, :, :, :))` won't work because it will perform `mean` calculation along just one dimension, which I just discovered would be the first non-singleton dimension (pretty useful info accidentally discovered). To make it work along the last three dimensions as  a whole, you can reshape it to a column vector and then use `mean` along the first dimension, like so -

```
mean(reshape(X(1,1,:,:,:),[],1))
```

Let's use this to verify results in the next section.

**Sample run with the listed inputs for verification**

```
>> dim12_idx
dim12_idx =
     1     1
     2     4
     3     1
     3     3
>> mean(reshape(X(1,1,:,:,:),[],1))
ans =
       5.3125
>> mean(reshape(X(2,4,:,:,:),[],1))
ans =
       5.0312
>> mean(reshape(X(3,1,:,:,:),[],1))
ans =
       4.5312
>> mean(reshape(X(3,3,:,:,:),[],1))
ans =
        4.875
>> out
out =
       5.3125
       5.0312
       4.5312
        4.875
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `[d1, d2, d3] = size(X)` and `d3` would automatically be `d3 * d4 * d5`?